# nginx try_files index conflict

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to achieve a setup with nginx to:

- use index.html for '/'
- clean up .html urls
- default to 404 if no corresponding file is found

My server block looks like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    index index.htm;

    location / {
        root "static";
        try_files $uri.html =404;
    }
}
```

Right now, visiting '/' goes to 404. I've tried common solutions like:

```
try_files $uri.html $uri/ =404;
```

but these allow both '/page' and '/page.html' as valid urls and I want to avoid duplicates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `root` directive has two problems:

1. It uses a relative path. When a relative path is used, it's relative to a default directory compiled into nginx. Do you know which one that is? It's best to specify absolute paths.
2. It is in the wrong place. The `root` directive should be specified in the `server` block. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).